# Custom Recycler View Circular List Arrangement

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there any Library or Custom way to arrange the Recycler List items as mentioned in Below Image?

[image]

Here Profile Image is Static that can be ignored and other circular Items are Recycler view Items for which I need the solution.

I have gone through many Articles and Libraries, but didn't found any relative method. Any Guidance will be helpful.

Comment: Can't it be achieved by RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager? with some tweeks

Comment: I think that to solve this problem you need to implement your custom LayoutManager. With this implementation you can decide how to display elements in RecyclerView

Comment: try this : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html

Comment: @Maddy: I think this should work with some customization. I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: @AzharBandri, here is a small example : https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/

Comment: @Maddy: That worked! posting it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to Achieve this using StaggeredGridLayoutManager as mentioned by Maddy.

The only Tweek I had to do was, adding Top Margin to 2nd Item in Adapter. Rest UI for following Items is managed by the StaggeredGrid.

Comment: how did you achieved it can you post some code examples?